# sqlite typeless columns and storage in .db file

Tags: sqlite, type-conversion

I have a SQlite3 table that has typeless columns like in this example:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
  Timestamp INT NOT NULL,
  SensorID,
  Value,
  PRIMARY KEY(Timestamp, SensorID)
);
```

I have specific reasons not to declare the type of the columns `SensorID` and `Value`.
When inserting rows with **numeric** `SensorID` and `Value` columns I notice that they are being written as *plain text* into the `.db` file.

When I change the `CREATE TABLE` statement to...

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
  Timestamp INT NOT NULL,
  SensorID INT,
  Value REAL,
  PRIMARY KEY(Timestamp, SensorID)
);
```

...then the values seem to be written in some binary format to the .db file.

Since I need to write several millions of rows to the database, I have concerns about the file size this data produces and so would like to avoid value storage in plain text form.

Can I force SQLite to use binary representation in it's database file *without using explicitly typed columns*?

Note: Rows are currently written with PHP::PDO using prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example in section 3.4 in the [sqlite docs about types](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) demonstrates the insertion of a number as int in a column without an explicit declaration of type. I guess the trick is leaving out the quotes around the number, which would convert it to a string (which, in the case of typed columns, would be coerced back into a number).

Section 2 in the page linked above also provides a lot of info about the type conversions taking place.

Comment: Right. Apparently when using prepared statements in PHP-PDO all fields are escaped, even numeric ones. Using normal (non-prepared) queries without quotes does the trick.